# Selenium-Python Client Library - Automating in Background

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying automate a login process to my web application using Selenium-Python Client Library. The ultimate goal is to learn Selenium's Python Client Library. So, I would really appreciate answers from those who are into Selenium-Python.

I current have a code like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Firefox() # Get local session of firefox
browser.get("http://myServer/WebAccess/login.html") # Load Application page
elem = browser.find_element_by_name("LoginID") # Find the Login box
elem.send_keys("Administrator")
elem = browser.find_element_by_name("Password") # Find the Password box
elem.send_keys("Administrator" + Keys.RETURN)
```

This works well but all happens in the front-end. I mean it literally opens up a Firefox, keys in the values, clicks on Submit, etc which is as expected.

I am just wondering, is there anything I can do to make all this happen at the background? Let us say I do not want to monitor what the script is doing. I just want it to run in the background. Is there any way to achieve this?

**EDIT**

Downloaded PyVirtualDisplay and installed it in my windows using the command `setup.py install`. Installed EasyProcess and Path module too.

Now I have a sample code like this

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver
display = Display(visible=0, size=(1024, 768))
display.start()
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://www.google.com')
print browser.title
browser.close()
display.stop()
```

I get the below errors on executing this code:

```
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\user\Desktop\Sel.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyvirtualdisplay\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from display import Display
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyvirtualdisplay\display.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pyvirtualdisplay.xephyr import XephyrDisplay
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyvirtualdisplay\xephyr.py", line 8, in <module>
    EasyProcess([PROGRAM, '-help'], url=URL, ubuntu_package=PACKAGE).check_installed()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\easyprocess\__init__.py", line 202, in check_installed
    raise EasyProcessCheckInstalledError(self)
EasyProcessCheckInstalledError: cmd=['Xephyr', '-help']
OSError=[Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified  
Program install error! `
```

Comment: PyVirtualDisplay requires Xephyr and Xvfb, which appear to be Linux-only services. I searched for a virtual display for Windows, but couldn't find anything suitable.

Comment: Jason, Thanks! I was searching too. I finally ended up with HtmlUnit to proceed with a GUI less approach. Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firefox (and other graphical browsers) require an X display. You can use a virtual one with the help of [PyVirtualDisplay](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyVirtualDisplay):

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
display = Display(visible=0, size=(1024, 768))
display.start()

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
... more selenium code ...

display.stop()
```

Apart from PyVirtualDisplay, you'll also need its dependencies xfvb and Xephyr (on debian: `apt-get install -y xvfb xserver-xephyr`)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am on Windows XP. I installed the PyVirtualDisplay module and use the code as updated in my initial post under EDIT. I however get those errors as mentioned in the original post. Any suggestion?

Comment: I installed the EasyProcess module and the old error has gone now. It now says `  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyvirtualdisplay\abstractdisplay.py", line 2, in <module>
    from path import path
ImportError: No module named path` Where do I download Path module for Python from? Google-ing did not help me. or I did not Google it effectively

Comment: I even now managed to get the Path module from "http://pypi.python.org/pypi/path.py/2.2" but then when I executed the code (that I EDITed in my original post), I still get errors as edited in original post

Answer (score 1):

You can also use PhantomJS and Ghostdriver to run Selenium without a GUI-based browser.

https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver