# Is it possible to hide a browser window in splinter python (both Windows, Linux)?

Tags: python, selenium

I wrote a program to take a screenshoot of a chosen webpage. User types an url and then my application takes a screenshoot of typed page. I wonder is it possible (and how) to hide a browser window? I mean, no to open it but take a screenshoot? thanks in advance :)

I use python 2.7 and splinter for this. Code below:

```
from splinter import Browser
import socket

url = raw_input('> ')

browser = None    
try:
    browser = Browser('firefox')
    try:
        browser.visit(url)
        if browser.status_code.is_success():
            browser.driver.save_screenshot('picture.png')
    except socket.gaierror, e:
        print "URL not found: %s" % url
finally:
    if browser is not None:
        browser.quit()
```

For Ubuntu, I found this: [Selenium-Python Client Library - Automating in Background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6924387/selenium-python-client-library-automating-in-background?rq=1) but how about Windows?

Comment: Works on Linux as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6924387/selenium-python-client-library-automating-in-background?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

You have a few options:

1. Use a "dumb" headless browser, like [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/). This is fast, and perfect for a quick visit and a screenshot. However, it doesn't understand javascript.
2. Use the [zope.testbrowser](http://splinter.cobrateam.info/docs/why.html) browser in your splinter tests. It's a headless browser, so it won't appear on screen. It understands javascript, but will take more investment to get up and going.
3. Just use [urllib2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16344700/take-a-screenshot-from-a-website-from-commandline-or-with-python) with some special headers.